# Accessing UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

UIButton within a UITableViewCell is set to selected. When checking the button property on didSelectRowAtIndexPath shows as false.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var cell:UserActionsTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userActionsCell") as! UserActionsTableViewCell

    if (cell.followButton.selected){
        //selected
    }
    else{
        // not selected
    }
```

How do I need to access the selected property?

Comment: You can use uibutton using tag. for e.g. btnDelete = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:8];

Comment: you should probably store the state in a model rather than the view

Comment: You need to maintain the state of the button in your DataSource and restore it in `cellForRow...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method in table `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

try this code :

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UserActionsTableViewCell // get selected cell and use cell subView contains..
if (cell.followButton.selected){
    //selected
}
else{
    // not selected
}
```

Comment: Keeping the reference to the custom cell type and this works. 

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UserActionsTableViewCell